# Enabling and Disabling GUI button Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, button, matlab-guide

This is a very strange problem, because I am quite sure the logic is proper but it is still not working. So when the GUI starts, in the starting function, I set most of the buttons to be inactivated using the following line of code for every button, Kbutton, Bbutton etc..:

```
set(handles.Kbutton,'Enable','off');
set(handles.Bbutton,'Enable','off');
```

Then, when the user clicks on any cell in the uitable, I use the cell selection callback to get the info about the contents of the cell, and re-activate the buttons that can be used from then on:

```
set(handles.Kbutton,'Enable','on');
set(handles.Bbutton,'Enable','on');
```

And till now everything is ok.
So then the user clicks on a button, say Kbutton, and the underlying function is executed thanks to the button's callback function. Once the method is ready I would like to return the buttons to their initial state i.e. inactivated. So logic tells me, re-put the initial line of code at the end of the callback function and done:

```
set(hObject,'Enable','off');
drawnow;
set(handles.BButton,'Enable','off');
drawnow;
```

Where the first line of code in the above snippet, refers to the button who fired the callback and BButton is any other button in the GUI.

For some strange reason only the second one is being enabled off. I.e. the button that fired the callback is staying enabled on :/

Has anyone encountered the same problem?
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be that you forgot execute `guidata(hObject, handles)` at the end of the callback function? There is an answer on Mathworks on [why this is necessary.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/47189-purpose-of-guidata-hobject-handles)

Comment: am I supposed to add that at the end of every callback function? however it didnt solve my problem

Comment: I also tried to use:

set(handles.KButton,'Enable','off'); 

in the callback function itself, still didn't work. and this is very important for the project, because once the callback executes if you attept to fire it again using the KButton, the program terminates to an error

Comment: I use similar code in one of my GUIs, so you are doing it correctly as far as I can tell. Did you create the GUI using guide? Does the problem occur with only one button, or with any button? It's possible that there are other settings that are overriding it, and preventing the button from being re-enabled.

Comment: in general, you should have `guidata(hObject, handles);` at the end of all functions that are auto-generated by GUIDE (in some cases, even in the local functions that you wrote yourself)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
set(hObject,'Enable','off');
```

to

```
set(handles.Kbutton,'Enable','off');
```

Comment: still! same thing, does not disable :/

Comment: debug by putting a break point in code and see if you can manually disable it

Answer (score 0):

You click on tools =>gui options =>Generate FlG file and MATLAB file